# My Redirect is not working on clicking in logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a user clicks on logout button it clear the token from my local storage also change state to logout but its does not redirect to I want as it click on the button it redirect to the login page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Logout.module.css";
import * as action from '../../store/actions';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';



class Logout extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           loggedOut:false,
           redirect:null
       };
   }
   handleSubmit =  event => {
       event.preventDefault();
       this.props.onAuth( this.state);
   };
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if(nextProps!== this.props){
           if(nextProps.loggedOut){
               this.setState({
                   redirect: <Redirect to='/login' />
               })
           }
       }
   }
   render() {
       return (
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               {this.state.redirect}
               <button type="submit">LOGOUT</button>
           </form>
       );
   }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
       loggedOut: state.loggedOut
   }
}
const  mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
   return{
       onAuth:() =>dispatch(action.logout())
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (Logout);
```

Comment: What do your props look like? Specifically `onAuth`.

Comment: onAuth it dispatches a logout function

Comment: my function onlogout is working but my redirect is not working i have problem in redirect

Comment: provide action files code i.e logout function

Comment: `
import axios from 'axios';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';



export const logout = () => {

    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expirationDate');

    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_TYPES.SESSION_LOGOUT

    };
}
`

Comment: You should use `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`. Please refer the official document - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change in the `if` statement.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       if(nextProps.loggedOut && nextProps.loggedOut!== this.props.loggedOut){
           this.setState({
               redirect: <Redirect to='/login' />
           })
       }
   }
```

Also, FYI, you should stop using `componentWillReceiveProps` hook instead use `componentDidUpdate` and check for `prevProps`. Read about deprecated lifecycle hooks [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if(prevProps.loggedOut && prevProps.loggedOut!== this.props.loggedOut){
           this.setState({
               redirect: <Redirect to='/login' />
           })
       }
   }
```

It would be much better to use `withRouter` and `history.push` instead of `<Redirect  to={"/"} />`

Answer (score 0):

It should not be like this, you should render the

```
<Redirect to={"path"}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for contributing but i was making little mistake in my code but now it is working goo hope the it will helpful for vendors.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Logout.module.css";
import * as action from '../../store/actions';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';



class Logout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedOut:false,
            redirect:null
        };
    }
    handleSubmit =  event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onAuth(this.state);
    };
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps!== this.props){
            if(nextProps.auth.loggedOut){
                this.setState({
                    redirect: <Redirect to="/login" />
                })
            }
        }

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                {this.state.redirect}
                <button type="submit">LOGOUT</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}
const  mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
        onAuth:() =>dispatch(action.logout())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (Logout);
```